# Python trying to read XML file with Open() to string is adding invalid characters

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following code where I am trying to read an XML file (.csproj) into string. Problem is, when I try to do so (see `file_content=f.read().replace('\n','')`), its introducing invalid characters before the '<xml' tag like 'ï»¿' (see the screenshot) and I get an error that the XML is not well formed.

```
def parse_csproj(repository_root, repository_name, source):

    # If the file is not XML, then a ParseError
    # is raised. Return None to indicate that the
    # file is not a csproj file.
    try:
        p = repository_root / repository_name / source
        with p.open() as f:
            file_content=f.read().replace('\n','') #I put a breakpoint here and I see invalid characters before <xml tag
            root=ET.fromstring(str(file_content))
            #root = ET.parse(f).getroot()
    except Exception as ex:
        return None

    # Extract the list of NuGet packages that are
    # used by the csproj file.
    refs = []
    for element in root.findall('.//{*}PackageReference'): #You need to add {*} otherwise it won't work. Or you 
        #will need to access based on namespace. Because notice in .csproj, the root element contains a namespace.
        ref = PackageReference(
            ecosystem = 'NuGet',
            repository_root = repository_root,
            repository_name = repository_name,
            source = source,
            package_name = element.attrib['Include'],
            version = element.attrib['Version'])
        refs.append(ref)

    return refs
```

[image: Invalid ï»¿ characters]

This is file I am trying to read:

[image: file type]

Comment: Are you sure about the encoding of the file you are reading ?

Comment: Oh the file is like a .csproj file which is indeed an xml file.

Comment: The file seems to have UTF-8 BOM. Use `p.open(encoding='utf-8-sig')`, otherwise it will default to `'utf-8'`.

Comment: Thank you that works. i agree its a duplicate of the post. I can delete this or leave it as it is.